# How to scroll two listview together

Tags: android, android-listview

I haven't found a suitable solution for this problem. I am implementing the lists inside of a fragment. I have two `ListView` inside a `LinearLayout`.

So say i have five items in List 1 and three in List 2. So when the user scrolls he should get an experience as if scrolling one single list.

As of the moment List 1 and List 2 have their own independent scroll behaviour. My code is below

**List.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_gray"
    tools:context=".fragment.MallListFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false">
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why you are not using single list ?please put some more information

Comment: I cannot use a single list since the two lists have a different arrangement of the content inside them

Comment: Use different views inside one ListView instead of using two ListViews.

Comment: He means a custom list view. Use a custom list view

Comment: @AshwinNarayanan can you provide any link for that. Thanks !

Comment: http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=9 ..start with this .. u will get an idea .. lots of samples are there just search in google

Comment: UPDATE: Now Support Library allows to make it easier with <NestedScrollView> and <RecyclerView>. NestedScrollView can contains any layout with number of simple or recycler- views inside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple way how to do it using CWAC MergeAdapter - https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

This library gives you a possibility to  add two different adapters to one - MergeAdapter, and this MergeAdapter to one Listview.

```
MergeAdapter mergeAdapter = new MergeAdapter();
mergeAdapter.addAdapter(yourFirstAdapter);
mergeAdapter.addAdapter(yourSecondAdapter);
mYourListView.setAdapter(mergeAdapter);
```

Comment: thanks..one more thing. I want the data of the list in my second adapter to be not clickable. Any advice on how to do that. I tried going to my xml and setting clickable to be false but it does not work if i use the setOnItemClickListener(..)

Comment: In the layout(parent) you use for row in second adapter setOnClickListner(null); Or check the size in onItemClickListner.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using a single ListView with section headers. Basically you create a custom adapter that binds two (or more) adapters and returns a header view when appropriate, as explained [here](http://pygmalion.nitri.de/android-listviews-277.html#Sectioned_ListView).